# Only begin stored procdure if previous value is less than new value being inserted into table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure. I only want it to insert new values if the date value is higher than previous record.

```
Department   Change    Date
------------------------------------
Catering        3      2018-01-01 08:09:00.000   - Current Record 

Department   Change    Date
-----------------------------------------------
Catering       3       2018-01-02 09:10:00.000   - New record to be inserted
```

I have this so far, but obviously the select is wrong. I want to do something like this before the `Insert` statement

```
 if select top 1 * 
    from  database.[dbo].[DepartmentChange]
    where Department = @Department
      and Date > @Date
    order by Date desc  
begin
```

please help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.  You say you want to do an insert, and yet your code doesn't have an `insert` statement.

Comment: You are missing the other half of your if statement, for starters. `if (select TOP 1...) < @YourInputVariable...` is probably what you are attempting, but it's hard to tell with so little code.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking, or trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vague question.  I'm assuming @Date, @Department are from the new record.  So maybe like this . . .

```
if @Date > (select isnull(max(date),'1500-01-01') from database.[dbo].[DepartmentChange]
             where Department = @Department)
   begin
      insert statement here
   end
```

Comment: @Joeysonic - If you only want to insert when the condition is met (and no ELSE) I would suggest adding this as a where predicate to your insert statement instead of making it so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty vague details here but I think you are looking for something like this.

```
if not EXISTS
(
    select * 
    from database.[dbo].[DepartmentChange]
    where Department = @Department
        and Date > @Date
)
    begin
        --do your insert
    end

else
    begin
        --do something else here
    end
```